# Sequelize unique key not enforced

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have the following data model.

```
const User = Model.define('user', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.ID,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.ID_DEFAULT_VALUE,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  merchant_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  }
});
```

When I call the `User.upsert({ merchant_id: id });` with the same `merchant_id` twice with the same value (let's say `1`), a new row with merchant_id `1` is created.

I've also tried adding the following to my model definition with no luck.

```
indexes: [ { unique: true, fields: ['merchant_id'] } ]
```

According to the docs, I shouldn't need to do more than add `unique: true` to the field option hash.

Using the following with Express.

```
"sequelize": "^3.23.4",
"sqlite3": "^3.1.4"
```

Comment: Are you using sequelize to create your database (code first), or just to interact with it (database first)?

Comment: Good question and I'm not quite sure I can answer it. I'm calling `sequelize.sync(...)` when starting the server. Not sure what other info I need to answer that question properly.

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether or not the database existed before you started using sequelize. My guess is no, since you're using sqlite. I'm not sure what the issue is -- my thought is maybe the database was created without the index, and the index was added to the definition after the fact, and `sequelize.sync()` against existing databases doesn't drop and re-create indexes? Not sure. If you're *absolutely sure* you don't mind losing all the data in your database, you could try using [force](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2670) to drop and recreate all tables.

Comment: You're right. I restarted the server, and dropped all the rows many times but I needed to **drop and recreate the table**. I'm sure there is something more delicate to create indexes but this is in development. Thanks for the help! I hope this can help someone else too.

Comment: You could take a look at their [migrations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/) if you want a declarative way of handling database changes. That being said, if you're still in development, it's probably simpler to just nuke it from orbit every time you make a change and use migrations after you go live. I often create a "seed" implementation during development to automatically insert some data back into my database after re-creating it.